# Socket File Transfer between Java Server and C# Client

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I'm creating a TCP server in java and a TCP client in C#. In my java server I can recieve and save the file in my server folder. The problem is with my c# client, the client is not sending any data, therefore the server is saving the file as empty. Any idea on what could be wrong? Here are the c# client code and the java server code:

```
    public void up( String nombre) throws IOException{

        /*FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(ruta+nombre);
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or 4096, or more
        is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        fr.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);*/

    DataOutputStream output;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

    byte[] receivedData;
    int in;
    //String nombre;

    try{
        while(true){
            //Buffer de 1024 bytes
         System.out.println(nombre);
        receivedData = new byte[1024];
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        //Recibimos el nombre del archivo
        //nombre = nombre.substring(nombre.indexOf('\\')+1,nombre.length());
        nombre = new File(nombre).getName();

            System.out.println(nombre);

        //Para guardar archivo recibido

        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/FTP/"+nombre));
        while ((in = bis.read(receivedData)) != -1){
            bos.write(receivedData,0,in);
        }
        bos.close();
        dis.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e ) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }


}
```

Heres the c# client

```
 ----------C# CLIENT---------
 public void enviarArchivo(string ruta)
    {
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,          SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect("localhost", 5000);
            IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost");
            Thread thread = new Thread(leerserver);
            thread.Start();
            MessageBox.Show(ruta);
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ruta);

            socket.SendFile(ruta);



        } catch (SocketException sE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al crear el socket" + sE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the address, thread, and buffer doing in this code? Are you sure you are connecting to the right address, are you sure the socket is connected, have you tested sending a file through any other means to debug the server. Can you conenct to another server to check the client.

Comment: I'm using threads to manage multiple conections. The address is the host address in this case is localhost and the buffer is for send recive files in  the client and server. Yes I have tested the server. Like I said, the server recieves a file but its empty. I think the problem is with the c# client but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, in Java you create a DataInputStream but never use it.  `dis` is unused.  It's weird to do that but probably not causing the problem.

Comment: Also your Java `socket` variable appears to be global, which could cause problems in a multithreaded environment.  Might want to show us a bit more code.

Comment: I just noticed the `while(true)` in your server code.  Why is this there?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as offtopic, there has been not enough research or debugging done on this application, there is no attempt to determine which end is at fault, or which end is working, no effort has been put into testing against other clients or servers. or to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.  I removed the infinite loop you had in the server side (`while(true)`) and did some minor clean-up.  You code basically works but it looks like you had a bunch of kruft leftover from editing (that while loop) and you had got lost, not reading the code carefully.

I made one small change to use a temporary file because I didn't want to bother to make an FTP directory on my computer.  Just change that one call to `File.createTempFile` to whatever you need.

```
public class ServerTest implements Runnable {

   ServerSocket server;
   Socket socket;

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      new Thread( new ServerTest() ).start();
      Thread.sleep( 100 ); // wait a bit for server to start
      clientUpload();
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         server = new ServerSocket( 7888, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost() );
         socket = server.accept();
         up( "ServerTest" );
      } catch( IOException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger( ServerTest.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      }

   }

   public void up( String nombre ) throws IOException {
      BufferedInputStream bis = null;
      BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

      byte[] receivedData;
      int in;
      int total = 0;
      try {
         //Buffer de 1024 bytes
         System.out.println( nombre );
         receivedData = new byte[ 1024 ];
         bis = new BufferedInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
         //Recibimos el nombre del archivo
         //Para guardar archivo recibido
         bos = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( 
                 File.createTempFile( nombre, ".test" ) ) );
         while( (in = bis.read( receivedData )) != -1 ) {
            bos.write( receivedData, 0, in );
            total += in;
         }
         System.err.println( "Total bytes uploaded: " + total );
      } catch( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e );
      } finally {
         if( bos != null ) bos.close();
         if( bis != null ) bos.close();
      }
   }

   private static void clientUpload() {
      try( Socket client = new Socket( InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 7888 );
           OutputStream outs = client.getOutputStream() ) 
      {
         System.err.println( "Sending data..." );
         byte[] data = "This is a test!".getBytes( "UTF-8" );
         outs.write( data, 0, data.length );
         System.err.println( "Data finished." );
      } catch( IOException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger( ServerTest.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      }
   }

}
```